# Customize Default Aggregation Function Names in AG Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

In AG Grid when row grouping is applied, there is an option of "Value Aggregation" within the Column Menu. This option has a sub menu that lists the available aggregation functions ("sum", "min", "max", etc) along with custom aggregation functions defined on the grid.

The default aggregation functions displayed here are in lower case and abbreviated. I would like to have them in title case and not abbreviated.

| Value Aggregation (default) | Value Aggregation (required) |
| --- | --- |
| avg | Average |
| count | Count |
| first | First |
| last | Last |

Is there anything available within the preferences or api to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by defining [Custom Aggregation Functions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/aggregation-custom-functions#custom-aggregation-functions)

In this case I'm just passing original aggregation function, but you could define your own custom ones as well.

```js
const gridOptions = {
  // ...Other grid options
  aggFuncs: {
    Average: (params) => params.api.aggFuncService.aggFuncsMap.avg(params),
    Count: (params) => params.api.aggFuncService.aggFuncsMap.count(params),
    First: (params) => params.api.aggFuncService.aggFuncsMap.first(params),
    Last: (params) => params.api.aggFuncService.aggFuncsMap.last(params),
  }
};
```

Here is a Plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GnC6spz2y516GW4b

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Russ. I was hoping to be able to remove the default aggregation functions in the mapping in this case - i.e. `avg`, `min`, `max` etc don't show up in the list of aggregation functions. Is there a robust way to do this - although `delete params.api.aggFuncService.aggFuncsMap.avg` etc is available I wonder if deleting ag grid defined functions is discouraged?